# Why does Eclipse sometimes ignore my breakpoints?

Tags: android, eclipse, breakpoints

I'm android developer and I use Eclipse.

Sometimes, when I am debugging my apps, Eclipse doesn't stop on my breakpoints. Eclipse shows a "v" symbol on the breakpoint.  I think this symbol means that Eclipse has passed the breakpoint without problems, but I would like Eclipse to stop when it reaches the breakpoint.

Of course, I have pressed the debug button (the icon with the green bug on it.)

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, it's because i have that activity in another process in the manifest... wow

Comment: This is my problem too. What do you mean by "another process in the manifest"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likley your source and class files run out of sync. If this happens clean and rebuild your project. This should make the issue disappear.

Comment: doesn't work.... i did a clean on the project and debug it again, and didn't work. Also i dont know how to rebuild an android project, but i think it's done every time you do a clean and a run/debug

Answer (score 0):

Old post - but pulled my hair out for a few hours with intermittent trace/breakpoints, so this may help someone.

The solution for me was simply to use the --clean flag to start Eclipse, so ./eclipse --clean